# RMAN DUPLICATE from backup without Target or Catalog: How is the aux instance created?

Tags: oracle, backup, windows, oracle-12c, rman

I am trying to duplicate an Oracle database based on backups to test if they can be used in case of complete system failure. Hence, I want to do this without a connection to the source database. I'm not using a Recovery Catalog.

I've read through all of the manual, but am stuck at [step 7](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmdupdb.htm#BRADV167) of "Preparing to duplicate a database" on the fourth point:

> 4. Start SQL*Plus and connect to the auxiliary instance as a user with SYSDBA or SYSBACKUP privileges.

The auxiliary server I am duplicating to is a clean empty installation with no database set up yet, as the manual mentions at [Step 3](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmdupdb.htm#BRADV765):

> Install an Oracle Database that is the same release as the source database. Do not create a database; install the software only.

Now, when running

```
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
```

I get

```
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Not entirely unexpected, as at no point have I set up a listener or Oracle service. So... what did I mis? Did I misunderstand the part about not creating a database? Is "a database" not the same as "an instance"? Did I overlook a part of the manual? And, what should I still install/create in order to have an "aux instance" i can start in nomount?

EDIT: This is in a Windows-server environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the typical error message you get on Windows without properly setting up the environment.

While the steps in the manual may work flawlessly on Linux/UNIX, on Windows you need extra steps. On Windows, you need to create a service with `oradim`, start it (if it was not started), and after that you can use `sqlplus / as sysdba`.

The bare minimum is:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=...
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set ORACLE_SID=test

oradim -new -sid test
```

This should automatically start the service, but if it did not:

```
sc start Oracleservicetest
```

And after the above, you can login to the idle instance with:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Comment: Oh my god! How is it possible that a product that costs thousands of euro's casually fails to mention this in its manual? I'm so glad this worked, but so annoyed (as usual) with Oracle... Your instructions could be copy-pasted directly into the manual, thanks for this!

Comment: Interesting sidenote. In Step 8 there is another mistake in the manual. It says you can skip to "config RMAN channels for use in duplication". Yet you should also read the next section first, as it explains you need to connect RMAN to AUXILIARY.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do a clone, you need to connect to the target database which is the database that you are cloning from. In this case you are doing a restore. So there is no auxiliary database. Just do a startup nomount, provided that you have a pfile with the proper settings. Then restore a specific control file as in "restore control file from '/path/to/rman/backup/****.ctl';". If your control file is labeled the same as the backups you can try "CATALOG START WITH '/disk2/archlog' NOPROMPT; Where the path points to your most recent backup. If the path of the restore is different then make sure that your pfile has the following:

```
db_file_name_convert='/from_path/','/to_path/'
log_file_name_convert='/from_path/','/to_path/'
```

You should also point the db_create_file_dest to the default directory for creating datafiles. As long as you have restore the controlfile, then you can just do the following:

```
alter database mount;
restore database;
recover database;
alter database open resetlogs;
```

And now you have a working copy of the database. You want to make sure that you don't use the newest controlfile available. You want to make sure that the controlfile is older than the newest archivelog that you have available.

Comment: The manual says I don't have to connect to a target, if I'm doing a clone from backup and provide the BACKUP LOCATION and SPFILE parameters. The problem I had is that I can't start a database in nomount, if there is no database, and the manual told me explicitly not to create one. As @Balazs Papp mentions, this seems to be missing in the manual.

Comment: So, I'm afraid you misunderstood what I'm trying to do, and what the issue was. Still, thx for the effort :)

Comment: When there is only one database that you are connecting to, then it must be the target and you are doing a restore rather than a clone. I think I completely understand what you are doing. I wrongly assumed Linux. Hence you create and modify the services with oradim. and if there is not control files for an database it will startup nomount by default.

Comment: I am quite sure you are mixing up target/auxiliary. From the backup and recovery user guide: page 25-5 -> "Figure 25-4 illustrates backup-based duplication without connections to the target or to the recovery catalog database instance. RMAN connects to the auxiliary instance of the duplicate database on the destination host." - , and page 25-22 -> "For backup-based duplication without target and recovery catalog connections, you must connect to the auxiliary instance as AUXILIARY."